# Ignite Thread Pool usage - how do I properly put data in cache in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, ignite

As it is stated in docs, Ignite provides system thread pool to process cache related operations. 
My issue is a data putting, but streaming and batch loading is not a solution, because that data comes from multiple clients through REST-queries, and fast write acknowledge for each query is required.

So I'm looking for a way to make cache.put() operation in parallel. And first question is - is it true that simple cache.put() is not executed in parallel?
I found out that I can invoke Ignite custom ExecutorService as following:

```
 ExecutorService exec = ignite.executorService();
 <...>
 exec.submit(new IgniteRunnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println("data put");
        cache.put(i, somedataobj);
                            }});
```

and then all the put operations are executed in parallel on all nodes (because I see "data put" in console output on all nodes). But I think it is not a proper way to make put in parallel, because data firstly sent to worker node, only then is put.

Another way is using Java plain fixed thread pool like that:

```
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            int t = i;
            DataClass dataobj = data().build();
            exec.submit(new IgniteRunnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                System.out.println("data put");
                                cache.put(t, dataobj);
                            }});

        }

        exec.shutdown();
        exec.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime);
```

But then I get another problem - data get loaded very fast (I get small elapsedTime), but appears in cache much later (when I do `cache -a` through ignite visor, I see how cache size is growing)

How do I properly put data in parallel? How can I use Ignite System Thread Pool to put data in parallel?

Comment: You get small `elapsedTime` because your code is borked. You call shutdown, you wait for **zero** milliseconds and then you decide that everything went great. There's no guarantee that all of your `IgniteRunnables` were even executed.

Comment: 0 means no limit, doesn't it?

Comment: Why are you asking me? If you think it means no limit, then surely you can show me where you got that idea? Are you writing code without understanding what you're writing?

Comment: @Kayaman I just use example, provided by Apache in their github repo - https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datastructures/IgniteExecutorServiceExample.java, which states in a commentary, that 0 really means no limit.

Comment: Well good, because [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) doesn't give any guarantees over that.

Answer (score 3):

Just use async API, for example, IgniteCache.putAsync method:
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#putAsync(K,%20V)

Comment: Seems like it works well. Does async put use System Thread pool? I've got x4 speed up, while SystemThreadPool is set to 2.

Comment: it should be executed in the striped pool, as it's responsible for basic cache operations.